# How to IsSummary=true using fhir-net-api?

Tags: .net-core, hl7-fhir

I am using fhir-net-api. I have implemented read operation on CapabilityStatement. Now with the read operation, I want to implement IsSummary=true search operation. I am not figuring out how to have resource elements with IsSummary=true using fhir-net-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [discussion](https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/dotnet/subject/FHIR.20Server.20with.20.2ENet) on chat.fhir.org, the recommendation is to let the FHIR serializer that's in the API take care of that. Make sure to add the "SUBSETTED" tag to the Meta data of the resource and serialize with the summary option set to true.